# Citing a paper from Integers

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

How would you cite an article from Integers (http://www.integers-ejcnt.org/), considering that papers published in the journal do not have an incremental page numbering, but are instead marked by an ID? Should I consider the paper ID as a replacement for the (more usual) interval of pages (Ex.: A01 in place of 27-34)?

Comment: The journal does not suggest a citation style for what it publishes?

Comment: The AMS's MathSciNet seems to use "Paper No. ##, ## pp." for this journal. [For example](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3083466): Pach, Péter Pál, Ramsey type results on the solvability of certain equation in $\mathbb{Z}_m$, Integers 13 (2013), Paper No. A4, 9 pp.